# threeJS, Need some advice to pick an item from a pointcloud with raycasting

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, point-clouds

I would like to be able to select a point from my pointCloud. To do that, I found a lot of examples:

[Interactive particles example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_particles.html)

[Interactive raycasting pointcloud example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud.html)

So I wrote the following code:

```
    function intersectionCheck(event)
    {
        if(pointClouds != null)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

            var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( pointClouds );
            intersection = ( intersections.length ) > 0 ? intersections[ 0 ] : null;

            if(intersection != null)
            {
                console.log(intersection.point);
                sphere.position.copy( intersection.point );            
            }
        }  
    }
```

That code was supposed to place a green sphere on the screen only if the user clicked on an entity from the pointcloud.

But it was false, the sphere appeard even if there was no entity, as shows the following screenshot:
[image]

It seemed that there was a problem with the size of my entities, because the function returned me a position even if I was far away from any entity.

So I changed the way that the position was selected. I checked if the distanceToRay of the point was smaller than sizeOfMyEntities/2.

```
    if(intersection != null)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++)
        {
            var testPoint = intersections[i];

            if(material.size/2 > testPoint.distanceToRay)
            {
                point = intersections[i].point;
                console.log(point);
                sphere.position.copy(point);  
                break;
            }
        }          
    }
```

Now it works fine, but I'd like to understand why it was not working before. Why is that verification not done in the intersection process?

And also I would like to know if my second function was ok, or if it's a weird way to do what I want. 
Is there a better way to do the same?

ps: I am new with all that kind of stuff, so if I am wrong please explain me :D

Comment: Look at `Raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold` and read the source code for `PointCloud.raycast()` to see what is happening. The code is not ideal. Maybe you can suggest an improvement.

Comment: Thank you for those indications.

I looked the source code, and it seems that it is because the value of the threshold for a pointcloud is always set to 1.

It works almost fine with my first piece of code when the threshold is equal to the size/2. I say almost because it detects the item well when you click on the corners, but as it's a square it works from a bit too far away from the middle of the side of the square. (it acts like if it was a circle)
 
Is there any reason for the threshold to always be set to 1 ? (it's set to 1 in the Raycaster params by default).

Comment: Moreover, it's way faster to directly change the threshold parameter in three js. I tried out with 800 000 items, I had to wait 1-2 secondes before getting a response, now it's almost instantaneous.

Comment: You wrote: "Is there any reason for the threshold to always be set to 1 ?" -- It has to be set to something... You are supposed to reset it to the value you want.